Unable to filter by child and extend the results to the grandchild in solr
What we need: We want all documents that have institutions in a specific range of latitude and longitude, and for these documents we want to return all the children of the document.
one document is like below:
{
        "optionId":568510,
        "id":"Major-568510-5",
        "optionName":"Major A",
        "category":"Major",
        "_version_":1802116777088385024,
        "institutions":[
          {
            "stateProvId":47,
            "institutionSpatialField":37.123,-81.213
            "institutionName":"University A",
            "id":"MajorInstitution-568510-406-4",
            "_nest_path_":"/institutions",
            "category":"MajorInstitution",
            "_version_":1802116777088385024,
            "degrees":[
              {
                "degreeTypeId":3,
                "id":"MajorInstitutionDegree-568510-406-20-3-5",
                "_nest_path_":"/institutions/degrees",
                "category":"MajorInstitutionDegree",
                "_version_":1802116777088385024}]}
          {
            "stateProvId":14,
            "institutionName":"University B",
            "institutionSpatialField":38.123,-80.213
            "id":"MajorInstitution-568510-408-4",
            "_nest_path_":"/institutions",
            "category":"MajorInstitution",
            "_version_":1802116777088385024,
            "degrees":[
              {
                "degreeTypeId":2,
                "id":"MajorInstitutionDegree-568510-408-19-2-5",
                "_nest_path_":"/institutions/degrees",
                "category":"MajorInstitutionDegree",
                "_version_":1802116777088385024}]}
}

Each document is a Major. Each Major has a list of institutions and each institution has a list of degrees.
We are using Solr version 8.1.
What we have tried:
We've tried using childFilter like below:
q=*:*&fq=category:(Major)&fl=*, [child childFilter="institutions/institutionSpatialField:[37.1,80 TO 38.1,82.13]"]]
Basically, adding a childFilter that filters for the range of lat,long that is searched for.
The issue with this is that the results stop at the institution level. Like below:
{
        "id":"Major-568510-5",
        "optionName":"Major A",
        "category":"Major",
        "_version_":1802116777088385024
        "institutions":[
          {
            "stateProvId":47,
            "institutionName":"University A",
            "institutionSpatialField":37.123,-81.213,
            "id":"MajorInstitution-568510-406-4",
            "_nest_path_":"/institutions",
            "_version_":1802116777088385024},
          
}

But, we want to also get the degrees for the filtered document.

By following this: https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/searching-nested-documents.html#child-query-parser
I think you can do: q={!parent which = '-_nest_path_:* optionId:*'}institutionSpatialField:[37.1,80 TO 38.1,82.13]&fq=category:(Major)&fl=*, [child]

when I see the results, I believe, what this query does is getting all the parents that have at least one institution with this filter. While, what I want is another step forward and also filtering all the institutions from the institutions list.
The result from this will bring a major that has an institution in the range of lat, long, but will also include other institutions that the major has.
The expected result is should return a list of majors that have at least one institution in the range of lat, long but also, only return the institutions that are in the range

Hmm okay maybe try replacing institutionSpatialField:[37.1,80 TO 38.1,82.13] with (+_nest_path_:"/institutions" + institutionSpatialField:[37.1,80 TO 38.1,82.13])
Something like that should work for you I think

should there be a space between + and institutionSpatialField?

no thats a copy/paste formatting error there should be no space. Also if it still returns all the child docs I would try using what I said originally with this inside the fq

I tried it with no space, I still got all the childs
When I try adding it with fq, I get no results. Below were the parameters when I got no results.
"q":"{!parent which = '-_nest_path_:* optionId:'}institutionSpatialField:[37.1,80 TO 38.1,82.13]",
"fl":", [child]",
"fq":"(+nest_path:"/institutions" +institutionSpatialField:[37.1,80 TO 38.1,82.13])",
